# Cloud Endpoints not accepting JSON array

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to build my endpoint, which accept JSON array of below format:

```
[
  {
    "test":"Math",
    "result":"Pass"    
  },
  {
    "test":"Science",
    "result":"FirstClass"    
  }
]
```

It will be a POST call with the above JSON to my endpoint.

I tried it with servlet too but did not get the required result, and also tried to with list and inserting in a new class and posting to that class. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is that an accurate representation of the JSON object which is being sent over? Because one does not simply send a a POST request with a JSON object of their param object to a cloud endpoint. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js) for a thorough guide to Endpoint API interaction from a javascript perspective - notice how the client library exposes an object "gapi" through which calls are made. If you're sending this JSON from an iOS or Android app, there are similar client libraries which can be generated for you by [a cloud endpoints build tool](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/endpoints_tool).

Comment: I'm trying to integrate my application with third party service who will POST the JSON to my endpoint in the above format(not the exact info) but the same format. How can I accept the JSON array with a POST call to my endpoint.

Comment: You cannot simply post JSON to an endpoint. I would highly recommend endpoints build tools to generate a client library for your target platform (web(js), android, iOS, etc...) 

Either that or learn the format the endpoint is expecting and create the exact same JSON object for your request, handle authentication yourself if needed, etc... 

If you have no control over the format of the data coming from the third party service, a work-around would be to direct the request toward your own servlet, which then makes the correctly-formatted endpoint call, and finally returns the value it receives.

Answer (score 0):

After much frustration, I resorted to reading the docs more carefully.  In that quest, I found an important note in the doc:
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/parameter-and-return-types

"Any type except a parameter or injected type is considered an entity type. ... Entity types cannot be annotated with @Named"

With all examples showing named parameters, I was stumped as the docs don't explain further, but then found a solution.  It ends up that if you do not have named parameters, everything is just passed in as a LinkedHashMap.  Usually, you can do any work you need to with just that data structure, but if you HAVE to have it in JSON, you can convert it.  Here are some examples:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "endpointIterfaceName.createItems", httpMethod = "post", path = "test/items")
public WhateverReturnType createItems(LinkedHashMap<String, Object> itemsMap) {

    // Do Stuff with map values
    return whateverReturnValue;

}
```

With this, you need to be sure that you post your data with the Content-Type of json (i.e. **Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8**).  So, for example, when testing, with a jquery ajax call you would need to set dataType to "json" or with Postman, you would select "Raw" then JSON (application/json).

If you really want to convert this to a JSON object in Java because for whatever reason you can not use a hash map, you can do the following in your method:

```
// Use gson library to convert the map to a string
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
String mapAsJsonString = gson.toJson(itemsMap); 
// create a JSON object from the new string representation
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(mapAsJsonString);
```

As a side note, if this is passed as Content-Type:text then the whole body will be in the map as the first key of the map.  You could do some inadvisable things here and just get that key and avoid converting the map to a string and then to a json object, but, like I said, that is inadvisable.  :)